# Opencv classifier update error

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, classification

I am getting an error while trying to update the CvBoost classifier in OpenCV, the error i am getting is as follows

**OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The new training data must have the same types and the input and output variables and the same categories for categorical variables) in CvDTreeTrainData::set_data, file /home/bsoni/Downloads/OpenCV-2.4.1/modules/ml/src/tree.cpp, line 172**

Basically i am working on a 2 class problem and initially i train the classifier with a set of SURF features. So the process is that i initially train the classifier using a set of surf descriptors.

data.surf_features are a set of 128 bit SURF descriptors
data.surf_classes are a set of class labels which are either +1 or -1

Initially i train the classifier using

```
void train()
{
    CvBoostParams params(CvBoost::REAL,80,0.95,2,false,0);
    aSurfBoost.train(data.surf_features,CV_ROW_SAMPLE,data.surf_classes,Mat(),Mat(),Mat(),Mat(),params,false);

}
```

following that i try to re-train the classifier using the code below

```
void train()
{
    CvBoostParams params(CvBoost::REAL,80,0.95,2,false,0);
    aSurfBoost.train(data.surf_features,CV_ROW_SAMPLE,data.surf_classes,Mat(),Mat(),Mat(),Mat(),params,true);

}
```

the only think i am changing is setting the update parameter to true.

I have checked the Mat.type of the descriptors and in both cases they are the exact same thing.

any suggestions solutions or possibly even workarounds would be welcome.